# PHP MySQLi Pagination LIMIT issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pagination

I am currently working on a pagination script for displaying records capped at 20 per page.

I have found a similar question on Stack Overflow, which had an example of how one would perform this. I've tried the code and made adjustments too, but I can't get it to function properly.

The code is:

```
$pages = ceil($rescnt['cnt']/$limit);

    $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        'default'   => 1,
        'min_range' => 1,
    ),
    )));
    $offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;
    $start = $offset;
    $end = min(($offset + $limit), $rescnt['cnt']);
```

There are 41 records in the MySQL database (0 - 40).

The first page displays correctly, with a `LIMIT 0,20`. However, the second page's limit is `LIMIT 20,40` which actually returns 21 results.

The scripts calculates that there should be 3 pages in total (20 on P1, 20 on P2 & 1 on P3) however, P1 has 20 & P2 has 21. P3 is empty.

I have tried altering the calculation of the pages etc. but it still won't work. Could anyone please give me a little insight into this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FROM 21 to 40, rather than 20.

The LIMIT clauses are inclusive. It is from Record 20, count 20.

LIMIT 20,20 = 20,21,22,...37,38,39.

EDIT:

You will see LIMIT 0,20 shows 20 rows, but they start at zero. Rather like an array key, this perpetuates through the iterations.

### BETTER:

You're updating the wrong columns.

First 20 results = `LIMIT 0,20`

next 20 results = `LIMIT 19,20`
final 20 results = `LIMIT 39,20`

```
LIMIT <start row>, <row count>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how would one set about having the  limit set to 0,20 | 20,20 | 40,20 etc. ?

Comment: use a PHP $var as a counter, for each output loop where you display your 20 rows, $var = $var + 20; starting at 0. then call the next pagination.

Comment: Your updated answer made sense. I now have a fully functioning pagination script. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

20 to 40 is 21 records. You have off by one bug. You should start off the next page with previous page last record plus 1. i.e. 21,40

Like 1 to 2 i.e. 1,2 is two records.